# Construct stl container after declaration

Tags: c++, stl

If I have a factor function `f`:

```
typedef std::vector<int> IntVec;
const IntVec f(...) {
    IntVec retval;
    ...
    return retval;
}
```

and I need to delay the definition after declaration as follow:

```
IntVec instance;
if (...) {
    instance = f(a, ...);
}
else {
    instance = f(b, ...);
}
```

Is there a suggested way to do it?

---

Now, I use pointer of container to do it like:

```
std::auto_ptr<IntVec> pinstance(NULL);
if (...) {
    pinstance.reset(new IntVec(f(a, ...)));
}
else {
    pinstance.reset(new IntVec(f(b, ...)));
}
IntVec& instance(*pinstance);
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntVec retval;`

All this creates is an empty vector. It is initialized, but as far as contents go, empty and you can add to it as you see fit.

Also,

```
IntVec instance;
if (...) {
    instance = f(a, ...);
}
else {
    instance = f(b, ...);
}
```

This is legal.

Instance does get overwritten by the return of `f` but efficiency hit is negligible, and I doubt you are running this function often.

Also you could do something like this..

```
IntVec instance = f(...?a:b,...);
                    //if
```

If your `if` statement is as simple as you show it.

Finally **your example with the pointer is flawed**.

I am guessing `pinstance` will be destroyed soon before `instance`, in which case `instance` becomes a **dangling reference**.

Comment: Ya, you are right. My example needs programmer to take care of dangling reference.

Comment: By the way, is 

    IntVec instance;
    instance = f(...);

as efficient as

    IntVec instance(f(...));

?

Comment: @wush978 I am not sure. All I am sure of is that the difference is too small to matter. You could run tests to check.

Answer (score 1):

Using C++11, swapping can be extremely efficient if your data type supports move-assignment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> inst;
    std::srand((unsigned)time(0));

    // code to set condition.
    if (rand()%2)
    {
        std::vector<int> v1(10,10);
        std::swap(inst, v1);

        cout << "V1" << endl;
        std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\n"));
    }
    else
    {
        std::vector<int> v2(11,11);
        std::swap(inst, v2);

        cout << "V2" << endl;
        std::copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\n"));
    }

    cout << "Instance" << endl;
    std::copy(inst.begin(), inst.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
V2
Instance
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
```

Note no content in V2, as it has swapped with the empty vector inst.

It looks like you've already gotten a handle on the dangling reference, so I'll leave that out for the second part of your question.